# Setting up a cookie via proxy

Tags: iis, proxy

I am using a proxy in the dev environment because I want to use real domain while using the "Edit and Continue" feature that works only on localhost.

I have configured `www.site.com` on my local machine with custom host. (simple html page)

I have this app: `localhost:9090` which is my asp.net mvc app on my local pc.
`www.site.com` call via ajax cors to `localhost:9090`, but localhost cant create cookies with the domain "**.site.com**".

So, I have created: `widgets.site.com` with custom host as a REVERSE PROXY to `localhost:9090` so I can keep using Edit And Continue Feature.

How can my localhost set a cookie to the wildcard domain "**.site.com**" ?  (Remember, `widgets.site.com` is a proxy to `localhost:9090` )

Here is the reverse proxy:

```
<rewrite>   
    <rules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:9090/{R:1}" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="(.*)" />
          </conditions>
          <serverVariables>
            <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
            <set name="HTTP_COOKIE" value="{c:1}" />
          </serverVariables>
        </rule>
    </rules>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
            <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://widgets.site.com/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://localhost/{R:2}" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
            <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
            </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/153409/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com#answer-153466) you should be able to `Set-Cookie` for `.domain.tld` and it should work for `www.domain.tld`. However from my tests it seems that it works on `domain.tld` as well (in firefox).

P.S. You can skip reverse proxy altogether by adding `127.0.0.1 widgets.site.com` to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`|`/etc/hosts`. Then your machine would resolve `widgets.site.com` to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks, If I do the host: `127.0.0.1 widgets.site.com`, I need to configure the project settings to use external host, then, ill loose the edit and continue feature (which is why i post the question).